I’m trying to install a remote controlled ceiling fan to fan/light switch
I have a hunter fan with pull chains that I would like to change to a more modern fan (unbranded). The existing fan is connected to dual Lutron fan/light switch that dims and controls speed of the fan fixture.
The new fan has ground wire attached to the ceiling fan mount, a receiver with one white and one black wires out to connect to power source and two wires labeled light that connect to the fixture’s male/female adapter and three wires labeled fan motor that also connect to the fixture through an adapter. However, unlike the old fan, the new fan doesn’t have a dark blue wire that’s connected to the red .
The wires from the ceiling are black, white, red, and ground.
Can someone help me with some solution. Either rewire the ceiling fan so I can use the wall switch instead of the remote or if that doesn’t work, how do I install single light switch to control the new fan.
dual wall switch
New Fan RC Receiver
New Fan Wiring

What make and model is your new ceiling fan?

Please post photos

The "BLDC" on the controller means it's for a "brushless DC" motor. You cannot connect that motor to your existing AC fan controller.

Send that fan back and get a different one
Unfortunately, brushless DC (BLDC) ceiling fans have the motor control logic built into the remote control receiver, so they can't be used with wall controls or "smart home" remote systems.  So, you'll have to send that fan whence it came and buy a different fan with a traditional AC motor in it instead.
